# Drywall repair and baseboards

Tags: baseboard

I have holes behind my baseboards from a company drying out flooring from a water leak. Do I need to patch the holes before putting up new baseboards?

Answer (score 2):

If totally behind the baseboards, it is up to you.

They will be hidden, but if it bugs you they are there, patch them up.

It is different if on outside walls and insulation/air drafts is a concern, then they should be patched, with insulation and vapour barrier fix.